# php script timeout after 5 minutes

Tags: apache-2.2, php, timeout

I am using wamp and my php script timeout after 5 mins.   I have changed these settings

> php.ini

```
 max_input_time 3000
 max_execution_time 3000
 memory_limit  1024M 
 max_post_size   32M
```

> Apache Config

```
Timeouts    Connection: 3000
```

Anything I am missing?

Comment: Can I ask why you need such a high timeout? You'll be running into other issues, like clients (browsers) submitting the request again. You should at least use POST requests for these long running scripts. Regardless, tasks that take that long, or are actually acting more like a daemon/server should possibly not be handled in a request like that.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeOut 1200`

You need to increase timeout on reading from module, not connection timeout. Connection actually happens way fast, there are few cases when it's timeout needs to be tuned.

Comment: so which setting it is, could you please confirm?

Comment: I typed it. Like literally.

Comment: I already set Apache Timeout to 3000

Comment: Connection timeout and read timeoute aren't same.